# Error reading files in Mosesdecoder train-model script (GIZA++, mgiza)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, smt, moses, giza++

I want to train an smt model using mosesdecoder (based on the moses baseline:https://www2.statmt.org/moses/?n=Moses.Baseline). I'm encountering the following error:

**this is the command:**

arisstamos@DESKTOP-DAJTUSV:~/mosesdecoder$ perl ~/mosesdecoder/scripts/training/train-model.perl \

> --root-dir work.en-de 
> --model-dir work.en-de/model 
> --corpus /mnt/c/home/arisstamos/mosesdecoder/Europarl_filtered_final.txt 
> --f en --e el 
> --external-bin-dir ~/mosesdecoder/scripts/opt/GIZA++ 
> --mgiza -mgiza-cpus 4 
> --parallel 
> --first-step 1 --last-step 3

**This is the output I'm getting:**

Using SCRIPTS_ROOTDIR: /home/arisstamos/mosesdecoder/scripts
Using multi-thread GIZA
using gzip
(1) preparing corpus @ Sat Nov 18 17:05:13 EET 2023
Executing: mkdir -p /home/arisstamos/mosesdecoder/work.en-de/corpus
(1.0) selecting factors @ Sat Nov 18 17:05:13 EET 2023
Forking...
(1.1) running mkcls  @ Sat Nov 18 17:05:13 EET 2023
/home/arisstamos/mosesdecoder/scripts/opt/GIZA++/mkcls -c50 -n2 -p/mnt/c/home/arisstamos/mosesdecoder/Europarl_filtered_final.txt.en -V/home/arisstamos/mosesdecoder/work.en-de/corpus/en.vcb.classes opt
/home/arisstamos/mosesdecoder/work.en-de/corpus/en.vcb.classes already in place, reusing
(1.2) creating vcb file /home/arisstamos/mosesdecoder/work.en-de/corpus/en.vcb @ Sat Nov 18 17:05:13 EET 2023
ERROR: Can't read /mnt/c/home/arisstamos/mosesdecoder/Europarl_filtered_final.txt.en at /home/arisstamos/mosesdecoder/scripts/training/train-model.perl line 975.
(1.1) running mkcls  @ Sat Nov 18 17:05:13 EET 2023
/home/arisstamos/mosesdecoder/scripts/opt/GIZA++/mkcls -c50 -n2 -p/mnt/c/home/arisstamos/mosesdecoder/Europarl_filtered_final.txt.el -V/home/arisstamos/mosesdecoder/work.en-de/corpus/el.vcb.classes opt
/home/arisstamos/mosesdecoder/work.en-de/corpus/el.vcb.classes already in place, reusing

**The directories are fine, all the files exist and I've checked the paths too. I've tried to change the file type from CSV to txt but the error persist.**

**What do you think that the problem might be? Thank you in advance**